# what does pam_env.so really do?

Tags: linux, authentication, pam

Having the following line:

```
auth        required      pam_env.so
```

Documentation says:

> The first module run, *`pam_env`*,
> optionally sets or clears environment variables
> specified in `/etc/security/pam_env.conf`. 
> This module is required—it must run successfully for authentication
> to proceed.

— [*Practical UNIX and Internet Security, 3rd Edition*
by Simson Garfinkel, Gene Spafford, Alan Schwartz
/ Pluggable Authentication Modules (PAM)](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/practical-unix-and/0596003234/ch04s05.html)

Great! What does really mean "run successfully" really mean? 
I know that it loads variables from `/etc/security/pam_env.conf`
(which, by the way, in CentOS and Ubuntu has all its lines commented out). 
Please could you explain me what does that really mean?

How can this module run unsuccessfully? Or merely loads variable, what has this have to do with authentication?

I've read the [`pam.conf` manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/pam.conf.5.html):

> required
>
>   failure of such a PAM will ultimately lead to the PAM-API returning failure but only after the remaining
>   *stacked*
>   modules
>   (for this
>   *service*
>   and
>   *type*
>   ) have been invoked.

Perhaps, I missing something, but it says me nothing about this topic.

All in all, why the type is auth, and not session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pam_env` man page says:

```
RETURN VALUES
   PAM_ABORT
       Not all relevant data or options could be gotten.

   PAM_BUF_ERR
       Memory buffer error.

   PAM_IGNORE
       No pam_env.conf and environment file was found.

   PAM_SUCCESS
       Environment variables were set.
```

Additionally, if your system has been corrupted badly, pam_env.so itself perhaps couldn't run (e.g. filesystem corrupted, or a 64-bit binary on a 32-bit kernel) and that will return an error value.

The reason it's in the `auth` stack is that subsequent PAM modules may rely on what has been set (and that's the reason that it is `required`).

Comment: IIUC that module is to prevent authentication in case of "OS curruption" rather a misconfiguration, isn't it?

Comment: I think that's right - really to prevent other PAM modules running without the correct environment.